# meteor + backbone multipage apps session get null after navigate

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, meteor

Hi everyone i making a web apps use meteorjs.
With backbone, finally i can make my web apps to be multipage.
this is my router.js :

```
Router = {
    uri: _.compact(window.location.pathname.split("/")),
    routes: [],

    addRoute: function(route, template, session, currTemplateType) {
        var segments =  _.compact(route.split("/"));

        var placeholders = _.reduce(segments, function(currentArr, piece, index) {
            if (piece.substr(0, 1) === ":") {
                currentArr.push(index);
                segments[index] = piece.substr(1);
            }
            return currentArr;
        }, []);

        this.routes.push({
            segments: segments,
            template: template,
            placeholderIndexes: placeholders,
            session : session,
            currTemplateType : currTemplateType
        });
    },
    getMatchingRoute: function(){
        for (var i in this.routes) {
            var route = this.routes[i];
            var data = {};

            if (route.segments.length === this.uri.length) {
                var match = _.every(route.segments, function(seg, i){
                    if (_.contains(route.placeholderIndexes, i)) {
                        data[seg] = this.uri[i];
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return seg === this.uri[i];
                    }
                }, this);

                if (match) {
                    return {
                        data: data,
                        template: route.template,
                        session: route.session,
                        currTemplateType: route.currTemplateType
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //no matches (add 404 or default template maybe?)
        return false;
    },
    run: function(){
        var route = this.getMatchingRoute();
        if (route) {
            var fragment = Meteor.render(function() {
                if (Template[route.template] !== undefined) {
                    return Template[route.template](route.data);
                }
            });
            Session.set(SessionLookUp.pageByURL, route.session);
            Session.set(SessionLookUp.currentTemplateType, route.currTemplateType);
            if(route.currTemplateType !== TemplateType.login){
                var isLog =  "true";
                if(isLog === undefined || isLog === "false")
                    window.location.href = "/cust/login";
                else{
                    document.body.appendChild(fragment);
                }
            }
            else{
                document.body.appendChild(fragment);
            }
        } else {

            var fragment = Meteor.render(function() {
                    return Template["404_page"](route.data);
            });

            document.body.appendChild(fragment);
        }
    }
};
```

and this is some of my pager.js :

```
Router.addRoute('/cust/login', 'login', UserType.customer, TemplateType.login);
    Router.addRoute('/cust/register','cust_reg', UserType.customer, TemplateType.register);
    Router.addRoute('/cust/profile', 'cust_profile', UserType.customer,"");
```

So this is my case,
user do login at localhost:3000/cust/login, after enter username and password, system will verify and navigate. If username and password match, so user will be directed to localhost:3000/cust/profile. this is how i navigate page :

```
Session.set(SessionLookUp.isLoggedIn, "true");
window.location.href = "/cust/profile";
```

but there is something bad here, after that code execute, session back to null or undefined again.
why this happend and how to solve this problem? Btw I create a custom login form, but i think the problem in how i direct the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meteor community has, by in large, picked [iron-router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router) as the router of choice for building apps. As opposed to backbone, it's designed specifically for meteor. For this reason, it may be difficult to find backbone-specific meteor help. Not being an expert in backbone, I'll do my best by skipping to the things which jump out at me as being incorrect:

1. When you manually set `window.location` you will reset the current connection to meteor. This will cause session variables, subscriptions, etc. to reset. You probably never want to do that. In iron-router you can call `Router.go` which properly maintains the browser state.
2. If you are using the native [accounts](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_api) packages, checking to see if a user is logged in is as simple as checking if `Meteor.userId()` returns a string. No extra session variables are necessary.
3. It is extremely unmeteorlike to be manually calling `document.body.appendChild`. Again, look at the examples for iron router to see how to properly use templates with routes.

Finally, I'd recommend reading the [meteor book](http://www.discovermeteor.com/) to better understand how all of these concepts work together. Even if you don't swap out your router, I hope this was helpful in some way.

Comment: thanks pal, now i understand and have strong reason why session become null. I have another solution, i use cookies for this case. what is your opinion about solustion that i use?

Comment: Using cookies probably makes sense if you are **not** using the native accounts packages (e.g. accounts-password). I'd have to hear a pretty compelling reason not to use those packages though.